# Unity : How can I get the list of gameobjects that are inside of Camera Frustum?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get all the game objects that are visible inside of a particular camera frustum. The game scene can be seen in the following image.

[image: See the image here]

The scene contains various game objects such as trees, buildings, cars and pedestrian. I want to access those game objects. How can approach? Which Unity method I can use? Please help.

Comment: Unity has a function OnBecameVisible: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.OnBecameVisible.html  (and OnBecameInvisible)

You could use that to maintain a list of the objects that are currently visible by the camera.
What exactly is your plan with those objects? Maybe there is a better solution when we know what you want to do with the GameObjects

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am trying to build a simulator for autonomous car. So I need all objects that can be seen from car camera. I need their  distance,position, rotation, state data for calculation. So is there any better approach than your previous suggestion?

Comment: Will raycasting be the better approach here?

Comment: I would say so too. There is no need for the car to know always know that there is a building at the end of the street, only if it is in a certain range.
But i would suggest you search for something like "unity self driving car". There should be plenty of tutorials that will show you how to do this.

Comment: You might also want to check out [TestPlanesAABB](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html). With `OnBecameVisible` the "object is considered visible when it needs to be rendered in the scene. It might not be actually visible by any camera, but still need to be rendered for shadows for example".

Comment: @Pluto , the code in unity scripting manual checks if a particular preselected object is within camera frustum, right? So for example if I want to check game objects that have a tag "car" is within camera frustum or not, first I have to get the list of all the game objects tagged car then run the TestPlanesAABB() method?

Comment: @TheSkimek , thanks very much  :)

Comment: You are dealing with  [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Always start the question with your goal to let others know why you are doing certain things. AI car behaviour can be implemented using raycast it has nothing to do with what is visible and what is not.

Comment: You need to use Renderer.isVisible instead of becamevisible. BecameVisible is shotted when changed to visible, but with isVisible you get if currently is rendered by your camera.https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html

Answer (score 2):

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class RendererExtensions
{
    public static bool IsVisibleFrom(Renderer renderer, Camera camera)
    {
        Plane[] planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(camera);
        return GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, renderer.bounds);
    }
}
```